# How can I change the return type of this function?

Tags: rust

I'm going through the [matasano crypto challenges](http://cryptopals.com/) using rust, with rust-crypto for the AES implementation. I have this function to do basic ECB mode encryption (basically taken nearly verbatim from the [rust-crypto repository's example](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/master/examples/symmetriccipher.rs#L17-L73)):

```rust
pub fn aes_enc_ecb_128(key: &[u8], data: &[u8]) 
                       -> Result<Vec<u8>, symmetriccipher::SymmetricCipherError> {
    let mut encryptor = aes::ecb_encryptor(
            aes::KeySize::KeySize128,
            key,
            blockmodes::NoPadding);
    let mut final_result = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let mut read_buffer = buffer::RefReadBuffer::new(data);
    let mut buffer = [0; 4096];
    let mut write_buffer = buffer::RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut buffer);

    loop {
        let result = encryptor.encrypt(&mut read_buffer,
                                       &mut write_buffer,
                                       true);

        final_result.extend(write_buffer
                            .take_read_buffer()
                            .take_remaining().iter().map(|&i| i));
        match result {
            Ok(BufferResult::BufferUnderflow) => break,
            Ok(_) => {},
            Err(e) => return Err(e)
        }
    }

    Ok(final_result)
}
```

The above version compiles with no problem, and works as expected. However, to make it fit with the rest of my error handling scheme I'd like to change the return type to `Result<Vec<u8>,&'static str>`. This is the function with that change applied:

```rust
pub fn aes_enc_ecb_128(key: &[u8], data: &[u8]) 
                       -> Result<Vec<u8>, &'static str> {
    let mut encryptor = aes::ecb_encryptor(
            aes::KeySize::KeySize128,
            key,
            blockmodes::NoPadding);
    let mut final_result = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let mut read_buffer = buffer::RefReadBuffer::new(data);
    let mut buffer = [0; 4096];
    let mut write_buffer = buffer::RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut buffer);

    loop {
        let result = encryptor.encrypt(&mut read_buffer,
                                       &mut write_buffer,
                                       true);

        final_result.extend(write_buffer
                            .take_read_buffer()
                            .take_remaining().iter().map(|&i| i));
        match result {
            Ok(BufferResult::BufferUnderflow) => break,
            Ok(_) => {},
            Err(_) => return Err("Encryption failed")
        }
    }

    Ok(final_result)
}
```

When I attempt to compile this version, I get the following error (paths removed for clarity):

```
error: source trait is private
         let result = encryptor.encrypt(&mut read_buffer,
                                        &mut write_buffer,
                                        true);
error: source trait is private
let r = decryptor.decrypt(&mut read_buffer, &mut write_buffer, true);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The only way I've been able to change this type is to wrap the original function in a conversion function like this:

```rust
pub fn converted_enc(key: &[u8], data: &[u8]) 
                       -> Result<Vec<u8>, &'static str> {
   match aes_enc_ecb_128(key,data) {
       Ok(v) => Ok(v),
       Err(_) => Err("Encryption failed")
   } 
}
```

What should I do instead of the above in order to get the return value to fit with the rest of my API, and why is the more direct method failing?

I'm using the following versions of rust/cargo:

```
rustc 1.2.0-nightly (0cc99f9cc 2015-05-17) (built 2015-05-18)
cargo 0.2.0-nightly (ac61996 2015-05-17) (built 2015-05-17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have come across a bug of the compiler. Your code should compile

You can `use crypto::symmetriccipher::Encryptor;` as a workaround:

```rust
pub fn aes_enc_ecb_128(key: &[u8], data: &[u8]) 
                       -> Result<Vec<u8>, &'static str> {
    use crypto::symmetriccipher::Encryptor;
    let mut encryptor = aes::ecb_encryptor(
            aes::KeySize::KeySize128,
            key,
            blockmodes::NoPadding);
    let mut final_result = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let mut read_buffer = buffer::RefReadBuffer::new(data);
    let mut buffer = [0; 4096];
    let mut write_buffer = buffer::RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut buffer);

    loop {
        let result = encryptor.encrypt(&mut read_buffer,
                                       &mut write_buffer,
                                       true);

        final_result.extend(write_buffer
                            .take_read_buffer()
                            .take_remaining().iter().map(|&i| i));
        match result {
            Ok(BufferResult::BufferUnderflow) => break,
            Ok(_) => {},
            Err(_) => return Err("Encryption failed")
        }
    }

    Ok(final_result)
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster how did you do that trick with the syntax highlighting colors?

Comment: Check the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30458728/revisions) :-)

Comment: Oh... I had tried `rust` but it was `lang-rust`. Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, you are running into [bug #22050](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22050), which coincidentally is the exact same library and trait you have! To work around it, add `use crypto::symmetriccipher::Encryptor;` to your code.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! Also for the syntax highlighting tip Shepmaster, that will come in handy.